# test local go module which is imported using replace directive and use vendor directory from main folder

Tags: go

MyExporter is my local module that I import in to main module using replace. I want to run tests in MyExporter using vendor folder at root of main project.

My directory structure for project is like this

```
bitbucket.com
|__agent
     |__Exporter
     |     |__MyExporter
     |            |__factory.go
     |               factory_test.go
     |               go.mod
     |__Runner
     |     |__main.go
     |        main_test.go
     |__Vendor
     |     |__bitbucket.com/agent/exporter/myexporter
     |                   |__factory.go
     |__go.mod
```

MyExporter go.mod file

```
module bitbucket.com/agent/exporter/myexporter
```

Agent go.mod file has

```
module bitbucket.com/agent

require (
    bitbucket.com/agent/exporter/myexporter
)

replace bitbucket.com/agent/exporter/myexporter => ./exporter/myexporter
```

My problem is

1. If I run "go test -mod=vendor ./..." it only tests in main_test run
2. If I use "go test  -mod=vendor exporter/myexporter" I get "package exporter/myexporter is not in GOROOT"
3. If I run "go test -mod=vendor bitbucket.com/agent/exporter/myexporter" there are no test files
4. If I switch to exporter/myexporter directory then run using "go test ./..." it works but not "go test -mod=vendor ./..." as vendor directory is at root of agent
5. If I run "go test -mod=vendor ./exporter/myexporter/" I get "main module (bitbucket.com/agent) does not contain package bitbucket.com/agent/exporter/myexporter"

The build doesn't have access to go packages, it relies on vendor folder, so do tests. I don't want multiple copies of dependencies in one more vendor folder inside myexporter. Is there anything can be done in order to run tests inside MyExporter using agent/vendor folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything can be done in order to run tests inside MyExporter using agent/vendor folder?

No.

You have to test your myexporter where it lives. Once it is vendored only the actual code is vendored.

The only thing possible is combine the modules.

It really boils down to: If you somehow need to test these two modules in parallel / in unisono then these are not really two distinct modules with *different* livecycles. And if these are standalone things with different livecylcles you can test the first, make sure it works and vendor it to the second. Then test the second, including its use of the first but without running the firsts tests as this is not needed anymore.

Comment: Thank you, I combined everything for now. I will probably move myexporter to separate repo altogether when it's ready for release.